# Update XML attribute with namespace prefix using xmltask and xpath in ANT

Tags: xml, xpath, ant, xml-namespaces

I am trying to check how to define the xpath in xmltask when processing an xml (change / update / parse etc)

On checking a few stackoverflow posts on similar topics, I could only reach as far as to understand how to "avoid namespaces" { by using ":" before each node's name - /:element1/:subelement1/:childelement2/text() } , when a node doesn't have xmlns prefix to it.

My objective is to update a weblogic xml , which has security namespace prefix defined for several properties , e.g below

```
    <domain xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls/1.0/wls.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/domain.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/security.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml/1.0/xacml.xsd" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain" xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security" xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <name>DOMAIN-NAME</name>
      <domain-version>12.1.3.0.0</domain-version>
      <security-configuration>
        <name>DOMAIN-NAME</name>
        <realm>
          <sec:authentication-provider xsi:type="wls:default-authenticatorType">
            <sec:name>DefaultAuthenticator</sec:name>
          </sec:authentication-provider>
          <sec:authentication-provider xsi:type="wls:default-identity-asserterType">
            <sec:name>DefaultIdentityAsserter</sec:name>
            <sec:active-type>AuthenticatedUser</sec:active-type>
          </sec:authentication-provider>
          <sec:password-validator xsi:type="pas:system-password-validatorType" xmlns:pas="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator">
            <sec:name>SystemPasswordValidator</sec:name>
              <pas:min-password-length>8</pas:min-password-length>
              <pas:min-numeric-or-special-characters>1</pas:min-numeric-or-special-characters>
          </sec:password-validator>
         </realm>
       </security-configuration>
     </domain>
```

I tried using the below xmltask command , but it doesn't work as the result is null , meaning that it cannot find a matching node.

```
    <target name="xml_parse">
      <echo> Executing the task for parsing an XML </echo>
      <xmltask source="src/config.xml">
        <copy path="/*[local-name='domain']/*[local-name='security-configuration']/*[local-name='realm']/*[name='sec:password-validator']/*[name='sec:name']/text()" attrValue="true" property="N1"/>
      </xmltask>
      <if>
        <isset property="N1"/>
      <then>
        <echo message="Value of property = ${N1}"/>
      </then>
      <else>
        <echo message="Value of N1 not set"/>
      </else>
      </if>
    </target>
```

The output that i get is -

```
    $ ant xml_parse -f build.xml
Buildfile: /users/fs1/user1/build.xml

xml_parse:
     [echo]  Executing the task for parsing an XML
     [echo] Value of N1 not set

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve parsing the value in the below tag, from above mentioned xml snippet -

```
<sec:name>SystemPasswordValidator</sec:name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not call the `local-name` function. In

```
[local-name='domain']
```

you look for a child element named `local-name` and compare its content with string `domain`.

Also, in the last two steps you fall back to prefixed names `sec:password-validator` and `sec:name` which won't work.

So try this expression:

```
/*[local-name()='domain']/*[local-name()='security-configuration']/*[local-name()='realm']/*[local-name()='password-validator']/*[local-name()='name']/text()`
```

Comment: Thanks , that worked ! Is there a way where we can specify namespace prefix in the xpath ?

Comment: @ch3tank I'm not familiar with xmltask but according to http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/#examples there does not seem to be any namespace support.